# Find generating set for a group

Tags: group-theory

Let H be the group of $2\times 2$ matrices with entries in $\Bbb  F_5=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$

$$ H=\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}
    k   & 0\\
    m     & 1
\end{bmatrix}: 1<k<5  ,  0\le m<5\right\}.$$

How to find a generating set for this group?
My confusion is in finding 2 generating elements of H 
There is some answers to my questions in this post however I want know hot to find the 2 elements in the first place not to prove thet they are generating set.

Comment: Just take all matrices in $H$. They generate $H$.

Comment: Isn'it $1 \leqslant k < 5$?

Answer (score 1):

The diagonal matrices form a cyclic subgroup of order $4$ that is not normal, and the matrices $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ m & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ form a cyclic normal subgroup of order $5$.

So this group is the nontrivial semidirect product $(\mathbb{Z}_5, +) \rtimes (\mathbb{Z}_4, +)$. 
You need two elements to generate it (it is not cyclic): for example, the generating elements of the above two subgroups are fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your group has order $20$, can you see why?

Here's an element of order $5$:

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} $$

Here's an element of order $4$:

$$ B = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} $$

Can you now prove $H=\langle A,B\rangle$?

Can you see why $A$ has order $5$? Can you see why $B$ has order $4$? Can you generalize this to the case of any prime $p$, and not just $5$?

Comment: But how did you find these 2 . @Steve D

Comment: @Rosa1: Can you see that $A$ always has order $p$? The topmost element of $B$ is $2$: can you think of anything special about $2$, when it comes to $\mathbb{F}_5^\ast$?

Comment: I don't see how to find the 2 generating elements @Steve D

Comment: @Rosa1: your questions are not well-posed. Please explain exactly what is confusing you. Are you concerned that $A$ and $B$ don't generate $H$? Have you tried multiplying some $A$s and $B$s together? Are you confused how I got $A$ and $B$? If so, have you read my last comment? Can you please indicate what work you've done since you've posed this question?

Comment: I edited the question @Steve D what I don't lnow is how did you find these to elements among 20 elements

Comment: @Rosa1: compute $A^2$, $A^3$, etc. What is so special about the $1$ in the lower left corner, that lets us get all values of $m$? What other values would work in the lower left corner? Now compute $B^2$, $B^3$, etc. What is so special about the $2$ on the diagonal, that lets us get all values of $k$? What other values would work in place of $2$? I've provided enough help now, you can do the rest.